# Редактирование данных asp.Net Web forms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-webforms

у меня есть 2 таблицы в базе данных Пользователи и Роли. мне нужно сделать страницу, на которой будут отображаться таблица пользователей и поля для редактирования. Я начал решать Посредством ObjectDatasource один для Grid (минимум данных), и второй для repeator, на котором расположены расположены все поля таблицы Пользователей.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptr" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsCustomersDetails" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <label id="hlblId" for="tbxID">Id:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxID" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>' />
        <br />

        <label id="hlblFName" for="tbxFName">FirstName:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxFName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="vldFirstName" ControlToValidate="tbxFName"
            ErrorMessage="Поле 'Имя' обязательно для заполнения" />
        <br />
        <label id="hlblLName" for="tbxLName">LastName:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxLName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="vldrLName" ControlToValidate="tbxLName"
            ErrorMessage="Поле 'Фамилия' обязательно для заполнения" />
        <br />
        <label id="hlblEmail" for="tbxEmail">LastName:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>' />
        <br />

        <label id="hlblLogin" for="tbxLogin">Login:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxLogin" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Login") %>' />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="vltrLogin" ControlToValidate="tbxPassword"
            ErrorMessage="Поле 'Логин' обязательно для заполнения" />
        <br />

        <label id="hlblPassword" for="tbxLName">tbxPassword:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxPassword" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>' />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rvldPass" ControlToValidate="tbxPassword"
            ErrorMessage="Поле 'пароль' обязательно для заполнения" />
        <br />
        <label id="hlblonfPass" for="hlbltbxConfPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxConfPassword" runat="server" Text='' />
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="vldrPassConf" runat="server" ControlToCompare="tbxPassword"
            ControlToValidate="tbxConfPassword" ErrorMessage="введенные пароли не совпадают" />
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="vltrPass" ControlToValidate="tbxConfPassword"
            ErrorMessage="Поле ''обязательно для заполнения" />
        <br />  
         <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="cancel-edit" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="cancel-edit" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

отдельно я сделал кнопку дляя добавления записей.

Данный компонент я выбрал для того, чтобы получить автоматическую привязку данных. Проблема заключается в том, что после того, как я выбираю строку в таблице на редактирования -  я получаю заполненные поля. Вставка новых записей мне недоступна, поскольку не проходит валидация на клиентской стороне.

Как мне можно переключаться между режимами, не используя кнопку Cancel.